# CSS3 make table fits better

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

How can I make the first row ( publiser?) to fit better? since when I put a check box there it automatically gets bigger than I need it to.

How to get it like image 2 ( sort of) ?
The publish? is going to be check boxes, 
beskrivelse is going to be description
and valg is a dropdown box.

[image]

to :

[image]

CSS:

```
.CSSTableGenerator {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border:1px solid #000000;

-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;

-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator table{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;padding:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:first-child {
-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:last-child {
-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:first-child{
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:hover td{
background-color:#ffaaaa;
}
.CSSTableGenerator td{
vertical-align:middle;

background-color:#ffffff;
border:1px solid #000000;
border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
text-align:left;
padding:7px;
font-size:10px;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:normal;
color:#000000;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td{
border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff5656 5%, #7f0000 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff5656), color-stop(1, #7f0000) );    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff5656 5%, #7f0000 100% );    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff5656", endColorstr="#7f0000");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ff5656,7f0000);
background-color:#ff5656;
border:0px solid #000000;
text-align:center;
border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
font-size:14px;
font-family:arial;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child:hover td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ff5656 5%, #7f0000 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ff5656), color-stop(1, #7f0000) );    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ff5656 5%, #7f0000 100% );    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#ff5656", endColorstr="#7f0000");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#ff5656,7f0000);
background-color:#ff5656;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:first-child{
border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

html code:

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
                <table style="width:670px;height:200px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Publiser?
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            Beskrivelse
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            valg
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                                                <td >
                       <input type="checkbox" name="check1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Poster på facebook gruppe
                        </td>
                        <td>
<select name="usergroups" id="ugroups">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
    ?><ul class="dropdown"><?
            echo '<center><br><option value="'.$postResult["gid"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option></center>';
     ?><ul><? 
      }
    ?>
</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                                                <td >
                           <input type="checkbox" name="check2">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Poster på facebook gruppe
                        </td>
                        <td>
<select name="usergroups" id="ugroups">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
    ?><ul class="dropdown"><?
            echo '<center><br><option value="'.$postResult["gid"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option></center>';
     ?><ul><? 
      }
    ?>
</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                         <input type="checkbox" name="check3">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Poster på facebook gruppe
                        </td>
                        <td>
<select name="usergroups" id="ugroups">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
    ?><ul class="dropdown"><?
            echo '<center><br><option value="'.$postResult["gid"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option></center>';
     ?><ul><? 
      }
    ?>
</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td >
                          <input type="checkbox" name="check4">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Poster på facebook gruppe
                        </td>
                        <td>
<select name="usergroups" id="ugroups">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
    ?><ul class="dropdown"><?
            echo '<center><br><option value="'.$postResult["gid"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option></center>';
     ?><ul><? 
      }
    ?>
</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check5">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Poster på facebook gruppe
                        </td>
                        <td>
<select name="usergroups" id="ugroups">
    <?php
    foreach ($postResults as $postResult) {
    ?><ul class="dropdown"><?
            echo '<center><br><option value="'.$postResult["gid"].'">'.$postResult["name"].'</option></center>';
     ?><ul><? 
      }
    ?>
</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td >
                         <input type="checkbox" name="check6">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          Poster innlegget på facebook veggen din
                        </td>
                        <td>
                    Post på veggen din?
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                          <input type="checkbox" name="check0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Vil publisere innlegget på din personlige fb side
                        </td>
                      <TD class=mainTxt><select name="usergroups0" id="ugroups">
            <?php
            $result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
            foreach($result["data"] as $page) { 



                            echo '<center><br><option value="'.$page["id"].'">'.$page["name"].'</option></center>';

            }   
            ?>
        </select>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do first is give table a width of 100% in your CSS. This will make sure that the table has the same size as it's container. Then you give all columns that will have data of the about the same sizes a width. Now the first column will use the remaining width. Here is a small example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#container
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    div#container table
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    div#container td#column2
    {
        width: 10%;
    }
    div#container td#column3
    {
        width: 20%;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="column1">Column one</td>
            <td id="column2">Column two</td>
            <td id="column3">Column three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column with a lot of data in it. You are not sure how wide.</td>
            <td>Data two</td>
            <td>Data three</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You write :

```
.CSSTableGenerator {
   margin:0px;padding:0px;
   width:100%; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
   border:1px solid #000000;
   ...
}
```

So the table will take all the place it can (it depends on the size of the container)

Moreover, by default, columns auto fit. And here it's the case : you didn't mention a precise width for your colums. But you can pricise it : for example

CSS:

```
.small_column{
   width:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class = 'small_column'></td>
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class = 'small_column'></td>
  ...
 </tr>
 ...
</table>
```

Comment: i dont get any effect on it when i use it in my code.

Comment: In your 'foreach', you should not use <ul> (or if you use it, you must close it at the end and use only <li> tag inside)

Comment: yeah, i will go trough my code after i get the check box to be smaller. i still dont have any effect.

Comment: I tried your code, with wrong values instead of PHP values and it works very well. can you post the HTML code generated by PHP?

Comment: you can see the live one if you would like to?:

http://malinpedersen.no/ ( login with facebook).

i also added the current html code generated with php now

Comment: hmm. it should show your groups on facebook etc.. 

well well, i need the check box table smaller :/

teamviewer?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Just add the generetad code for the table you shown us in your print screens (ctrl+u for example in firefox)

Comment: For me, the only problem comes from the <input type = 'checkbox' />. What is the CSS code for it? did you fixed a width for the input? As you can see int my own screenshot it works good for me, so it may come from another piece of code in your page. maybe an unclosed tag (their are a lot of HTMN mistakes in your code) or another CSS witch is conflicted. You can retry and specify a width in the first colomn and overflow:hidden; but it will not solve the problem correctly.

Comment: hmm. even when i have a css code for the checkbox it wont do anything.  even with .checkbox {
    width: 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

remove all the width, so each row will take only the space of the longest cell in the column.

Then, add this css rule to your `table`:

```
max-width: 100%
```

if you don't like multiple rows for a specific cell, add also this rule to `td`

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

**warning**: if you use nowrap, a very long data in a cell it's able to go out of fixed dimension of 100% of the table.

---

EDIT
Another trick: set width for certain columns (but not all) as percent.

so:

```
#mytable {
 width: 98%; //so you can ad shadows and padding to parent container
}

#myFirstTdOfFirstCol {

}

#myFirstTdOfSecondCol{
 width: 18%;
}

#myFirstTdOfThirdCol {
 width: 32%;
}
```

with those rules table it's resizable and just the first column will be resized if needed.
Of course to obtain an elastic behaviour set `max-width` and not width to the table.

---

2nd EDIT :

```
   <table style="width:670px;height:200px">
```

have to be:

```
   <table>
```

change this one too:

```
.CSSTableGenerator table{
max-width: 98%;
   margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

---

3rd EDIT:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBzsB/)

works perfectly with my suggestions on 2nd and original post.
But
1) If you want shadow appear to the table, apply it to the table, not to container DIV.

2) Dropdown on select must have one or more `<option>`, not an unordered list `<ul>` with option inside.

Comment: Dear MrPk, i did what you said, but nothing difference im afraid :/

Comment: did your 3rd edit now.
tried you 2nd too, no effect :c

Comment: 3rd edit, but it's the same. Fix your wrong html too.